# Binding single record

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I'm playing around with WPF and LINQ, and stuck at the following point with no clue on how to show a single record, all of the examples I found show how to present a list, but not a single record.
I have prepared a user control that should show one record at a time, in my example a Customer, showing its' Id, Given Name and Surname, here it is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SportsClubsManagement.CustomersManagement.CustomerData"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <Grid DataContext="Binding Customer">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Id" Height="30" Width="70" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="70" Name="Id" Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Given Name" Height="30" Width="70" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="70" Name="GivenName" Text="{Binding Path=GivenName}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Surname" Height="30" Width="70" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Height="20" Width="70" Name="Surname" Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="New record" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="Next record" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="Prev record" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I also have created a table with several records and a class to represent a customer which also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
    public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Fields

        private String id;

        private String givenName;
        private String surname;

        #endregion
        #region Properties

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Storage="id", Name="Id")]
        public String Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
        }

        [Column(Storage="givenName", Name="GivenName")]
        public String GivenName
        {
            get { return this.givenName; }
            set {
                if (this.givenName != value)
                {
                    this.givenName = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("GivenName");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="surname", Name="Surname")]
        public String Surname
        {
            get { return this.surname; }
            set {
                if (this.surname != value)
                {
                    this.surname = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members" 

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(String name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Now in the code behind the user control I have a realy simple code that connect to the db and gets a record:

```
public partial class CustomerData : UserControl
    {

        private int curCustSeqNum;

        private Data.Customer customer;

        public Data.Customer Customer
        {
            get
            {
                return customer;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customer = value;
            }
        }

        private IQueryable<Data.Customer> custQuery;

        public CustomerData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=WIN-EL78137MUMS\SQLEXPRESS;database=PlayGround;integrated security=SSPI");

            // Get a typed table to run queries.
            Table<Data.Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Data.Customer>();
            //db.Log = Console.Out;

            custQuery =
                from cust in Customers
                orderby cust.Id
                select cust;

            curCustSeqNum = 0;

            Customer = custQuery.Skip(curCustSeqNum).Take(1).First();

        }
    }
```

But how can I bind the textboxes to the current selected Customer? You can see my last guess, after defining resources etc. But every time I miss something. I would like to know how can I achieve that in XAML, and in code behind. Basically after that I would be able to use the curCustSeqNum to skip to the following record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CustomerData` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so when you set Customer in the constructor the xaml has no Idea it has changed.

Example:

```
public partial class CustomerData : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int curCustSeqNum;
    private Data.Customer customer;
    private IQueryable<Data.Customer> custQuery;

    public Data.Customer Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set { this.customer = value; OnPropertyChanged("Customer"); }
    }

    public CustomerData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set the datacontext
        DataContext = this;

        ................

        Customer = custQuery.Skip(curCustSeqNum).Take(1).First();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(String name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

also mentioned by someone else, you DataContext binding on the Grid is invalid

```
 <Grid DataContext="Binding Customer">
```

should be

```
 <Grid DataContext="{Binding Customer}">
```

Comment: This seems to work, but only one way. What did I miss that doesn't allow it to write changes back? Another question - Should I remove the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged from Customer class, it seems to be useless? And the last one for now is - What is the purpose of "DataContext = this;" you've added to the constructor? without it it doesn't work, as far as I understand it adds DataContext to the user control specifying that it should look locally, but we also specified DataContext for the Grid, and this should rewrite parent's DataContext, isn't it so? And lots of thanks!

Comment: You should keep `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Customer` class as it will be needed to update the UI if any of the values change, The `DataContext` set in the constructor tell the `UserControl` to look locally this way you can access the `Customer` property, the `DataContext` on the `Grid` sets its context to the `Customer` object, this means anything on the `Grid` can access only properties from inside the `Customer` property, All of these should work TwoWay (except Id) setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the TextBoxes e.g: `Text="{Binding GivenName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" `

Comment: I understand, then my last question is about moving the "DataContext = this;" line out to XAML, I found that it's possible to specify for user control DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}", and it works, is it the right way to do it? and are there any other ways to make the property available in XAML?

Comment: Well some more investigation shows that these ways are also working:  
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  
An additional way is to set a name to user control and then to bind using the ElementName and specifying the property in Path.  
Are there additional ways? For example without naming? And is there a way I can bind content of some control without specifying DataContext for parents, like using some kind of a long Binding expression?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd make a "CurrentItem" object inside of your ViewModel in which you'd initialize on a SelectionCommand. In your case, you'd bind your "Customer" on your SelectionCommand in which you'd run a Customer.Get(id) command to obtain the current customer. You can then bind your controls to the "CurrentCustomer" object of the fields for each control.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand your point. More words please:) If not an example then maybe some kind of short guidelines would be perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Try set your Datacontext to

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=Customer}"
```

I realise that path is implied, however i have run into this problem myself  and this solved it for me.

Comment: are you including {} ?

Comment: Yes, sure, it was the first thing I fixed, tried to specify the mode already, but it didn't help either...